# Solving dependency google (com.google.common.base) in karaf

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, guava, apache-karaf

I have one project in karaf (version 3.0.3) with multi modules. I neeed the dependecies to one module - google-http-client.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.30.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In running karaf I found the error with `com.google.common.base`

```
Unable to resolve 367.0: missing requirement [367.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.api.client.http)(version>=1.30.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 368.0: missing requirement [368.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.google.common.base)(version>=26.0.0)(!(version>=27.0.0)))]
```

To solve the problem with `com.google.common.base` i use the package [google guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava). In `maven-bundle-plugin` I import the guava package.

I checked the MANIFEST file and had the next versions to packages, but now I have the same error. Can you help me, please?

`com.google.api.client.http; version="[1.30,2)"`

`com.google.common.base;version="[26.0,0)"`

**My Solution**: To solve this problem, I changed the google http client version (lower)...

Comment: I think you can solve this the same way you did with the http-client. Add a dependency to guava-jre (version 26.0) to your pom, and embed the dependency with the maven-bundle-plugin.

Comment: Yes, I do. But i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

These dependencies all seem to be OSGi bundles already. So do not embed them and instead install them bundles with their maven coordinates.

Try to install google-http-client in Apache Karaf using the install -s mvn:... command.
It will show you the packages this bundle needs. Then install the dependencies in the same way until you get no more resolve error.

Then put these dependencies in a feature file together with your bundle so next time installation is easier.